# How could GMT commandline not be working from one directory (but working from all others fine)?

Tags: bash

I have been using a script launching [GMT (General Mapping Tool)](https://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/) commandlines from a directory for a while. But now, the GMT commandline is not working in this directory anymore. It just enters and does not output anything, even informations on the version of the commandline.

```
/media/data/user/weird_directory/child_directory
```

This weird behavior is only located in the script directory though (weird_directory), and the commandline is working in the child (child_directory) and parent directories (user). I can thus launch my script only from those parent and child directories.

Do you have any idea what I did? What can I do to undo it?

The commandline which gives me problem is:

```
gmt --version
```

My path is:

```
/usr/local/src/SW/BIN/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/src/SW/QT5/5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc_64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/media/data/STUD/aargentin/bin
```

My .bashrc only has inside:

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions
```

Here is my directory content when I use ls -a:

```
0        
0]              
.        
..      
1000705   
1000799 
1000849  
1000858  
1000151  
1000507  
1001158  
1001333  
1001343  
1001563 
1001669  
1001741  
1001777  
1001805  
1001834    
1002029 
1002087  
1002125  
100216   
1002282  
1002310   
1002387 
1002647  
1002678  
1002700  
100273   
100319   
100325   
1003326  
10036    
1003615  
1003842  
1004278  
1004362  
1004398  
1004884  
1004974  
1005068  
1005082  
1005205  
1005411  
1005791  
1005832  
1005873  
1006295   
1006696 
100682   
100706   
1007061  
1007533  
1007635   
1007766      
1007871          
cut_DEMgrd.grd           
cut_only_rockfalls_DEM.grd   
cut_rockfallgrd.grd 
cut_without_rockfalls_DEM.grd                   
DEMgrd.grd        
dhm_at_lamb_10m_2018_part1_depressionless.tif    
dhm_at_lamb_10m_2018_part1_depressionless.tif.aux.xml                
gmt.conf      
gmt.history     
kdtpTC3JJ                                              
only_rockfalls_DEM.grd                
rockfallgrd.grd             
subtract_rockfall_to_flt_DEM.sh  
subtract_rockfall_to_flt_DEM.sh~                                            
without_rockfalls_DEM.grd
```

`gmt.history` is empty and `gmt.conf` only contains a printing option:

```
#
# GMT 5.4.2 Defaults file
#
# PostScript Parameters
#
PS_MEDIA                       = a2
```

Comment: You should post the script content, and the directories's content, just to start. The script could try to access a file, or use some named pipes, or whatever. Even the PATH variable can play a role. And, if you don't post a script, then your question is not a programming question and is out-of-scope in this site.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I tried deleting the `gmt.history` file that was empty, and the gmt command now works again.